# Convert given string to list of integers in Kotlin?

Tags: string, list, kotlin

I want to convert a user given string to list of integers.
If i write 12345 i want [1,2,3,4,5]
I am trying this code to achieve it but gives an exception.

```
fun main() {
    println("Enter Number")
    var numberList = readLine().toString().split("").map { it.toInt() }
    println(number)
}
```

This gives a NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

If i remove .map from it and enter 12345 numberList becomes [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]

But if i change delimiter to " " -with SPACE- and enter two numbers as 12 345 numberList becomes [12, 345]

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate the string's characters using `map` directly.

With Kotlin >= 1.6:

```kotlin
var numberList = readln().map { it.digitToInt() }
```

With Kotlin >= 1.5 but < 1.6:

```kotlin
val input = readLine() ?: error("Missing input")
var numberList = input.map { it.digitToInt() }
```

With Kotlin < 1.5:

```kotlin
val input = readLine() ?: error("Missing input")
var numberList = input.map { "$it".toInt() }
```

The character is converted to a string using `"$it"` because `Char.toInt()` would return the ASCII code of the character instead of the value represented by the digit. `String.toInt()` actually parses the number represented by the string in base 10.

This possibly unexpected behaviour is the reason `Char.digitToInt()` and `Char.code` were introduced in Kotlin 1.5.

Comment: this gives the same exception

Comment: i am sorry i tried this code andit works now thank you var number = readLine().toString().map { "$it".toInt() }

Comment: You shouldn't use `toString()` as a way to work around `readLine()`'s nullable type. You should either deal with the error explicitly like I did in my answer, or use `!!` to assert that there is some input.

Comment: @SerdarÇivi *this gives the same exception* - what exception? The `NumberFormatException`? With what input did you get this exception? This code doesn't split, so you shouldn't have the same empty string issues as long as the number that's input is valid

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to split the input string using `split()`, as Kotlin strings already support a `toCharArray()` function which returns an array containing each character in the string.

```kotlin
val input = "12345"
val result = input.toCharArray().map(Character::getNumericValue)
println(result)  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `"12345".map(Char::digitToInt)`.

Comment: There is no need to convert to `CharArray` because `String` is already `Iterable<Char>`

Comment: i can't make it work in (Character::getNumericValue) it says Overload resolution ambiguity